# For a React project, how to run the package.json "scripts" command on Bash?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vite

If I create a React project on the local computer (I am using Vite), there is a package.json file that contains

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
```

so as I understand it, that means I can do `npm run dev`, with the `npm run` meaning run one of those `"scripts"`, and `npm run dev` means run that `"dev"` one.

So if I want to run the `vite` on Bash, what should I do?

I found I could do a `npx vite` or `npm i -g vite` once and then `vite`, and possibly invoke it through the path into `node_modules`. However, what is a standard way to do it?

(I want to do `npm run dev` with the `vite` running as `vite --open`, but I found that I cannot do that on the command line, but need to modify the package.json file. Right now I want to create a Bash alias to create the app using Vite, do an `npm i` and start up the dev server using `vite --open`, so I can't modify the package.json using this alias. (maybe I can use sed or awk but I don't want to do it that way because it is a bit hacky))

Answer (score 1):

Like you write, the npm `scripts` section is for running commands using `npm run`. The key (left) is the command alias and the value (right) is the command to run.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite"
}
```

So `npm run dev` will execute the command `vite`.

The tricky part is to pass flags like `--open` to the `vite` command. If you run `npm run dev --open` then the `--open` flag is passed to `npm` and not to `vite`. `npm` ignores unknown flags, so `--open` is ignored.

To pass `--open` to vite, use the bash double dash `--` to terminate input to `npm` first:

```
npm run dev -- --open
```

For more information about double dash see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean).

Comment: that's cool.  It works. I will wait and see how to run `vite` from command line and see which one is the accepted answer